# How to overwrite files generated by filecontents environment

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable, filecontents

I am using latex to generate figures, here is a simple example.

```
\documentclass[
border={0mm 0mm 0mm 0mm}, % left bottom right top
]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,stackengine}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}

\begin{document}
    
    \pgfplotsset{width=5cm,height=5cm,grid style={dashed}}
    \begin{filecontents}{curves.txt}
        x  y1 y2
        1  1  2
        2  4  5
        3  2  3
        4  6  7
        5  5  6
        6  6  7
        7  9  5
        8  5  8
    \end{filecontents}
    % command in the matlab
    % [Time_Series_Plotted',p_total_from_TU(:,Time_Series_Plotted)',p_total_from_TU_CHP(:,Time_Series_Plotted)',p_total_from_TU_CHP_WF(:,Time_Series_Plotted)',p_total_of_loads(:,Time_Series_Plotted)',p_total_from_TU_CHP_WF_WCur(:,Time_Series_Plotted)']
    \pgfplotstableread[skip first n=5,]{curves.txt}{\curves}% 2+4 for filecontents header
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}
                [color=black,grid=major,use units, xlabel=x, ylabel=y,
                legend style={draw=none,fill=none,legend image post style={scale=1}, font=\scriptsize}, legend cell align={left}, legend pos=north west,]
                \addplot[dashed,draw=green, line width=1] table [x index=0,y index=1, ]{\curves};
                \addplot[       draw=green, line width=1] table [x index=0,y index=2, ]{\curves};
                \legend{curve1, curve2};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I use `\begin{filecontents}` and `\end{filecontents}` to create the .txt file to store the data for `tikzpicture`. Then, after compiling the latex code, I have a curves.txt file in the folder.

However, when adjust parameters of curves in the latex file. I should delete the curves.txt file firstly, and then compile the latex code. If not, the latex will still draw curves using old values of curves.txt.

Hence, are there some methods to delete the curves.txt file after generate the pdf file, or cover the old curves.txt file each time when complie the latex code, or just let `pgfplots` read data from the latex code without reading from files?

Comment: your title asks about deleting `aux` and `log` but your question is about completely different files, please edit the title or question to match each other

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need an external file and adjusting the values in the code below is just as easy as with `filecontents`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{width=5cm,height=5cm,grid style={dashed}}
\pgfplotstableread{
  x  y1 y2
  1  1  2
  2  4  5
  3  2  3
  4  6  7
  5  5  6
  6  6  7
  7  9  5
  8  5  8
}{\curves}
\begin{axis}[
  color=black,
  grid=major,
  use units,
  xlabel=x,
  ylabel=y,
  legend style={
    draw=none,
    fill=none,
    legend image post style={scale=1},
    font=\scriptsize,
  },
  legend cell align=left,
  legend pos=north west,
]
\addplot[dashed, draw=green, line width=1] table [x index=0,y index=1, ]{\curves};
\addplot[        draw=green, line width=1] table [x index=0,y index=2, ]{\curves};
\legend{curve1, curve2}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Seconds earlier. ;-)

Comment: Not even a full minute! Sorry! 

Answer (score 6):

You can use `\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{curves.txt}...\end{filecontents*}` to ensure that your `.txt` file is recreated:

```
\documentclass[
border={0mm 0mm 0mm 0mm}, % left bottom right top
]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,stackengine}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}

\begin{document}
    
    \pgfplotsset{width=5cm,height=5cm,grid style={dashed}}
    \begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{curves.txt}
        x  y1 y2
        1  1  2
        2  4  5
        3  2  3
        4  6  7
        5  5  6
        6  6  7
        7  9  5
        8  5  8
    \end{filecontents*}
    % command in the matlab
    % [Time_Series_Plotted',p_total_from_TU(:,Time_Series_Plotted)',p_total_from_TU_CHP(:,Time_Series_Plotted)',p_total_from_TU_CHP_WF(:,Time_Series_Plotted)',p_total_of_loads(:,Time_Series_Plotted)',p_total_from_TU_CHP_WF_WCur(:,Time_Series_Plotted)']
    \pgfplotstableread[skip first n=5,]{curves.txt}{\curves}% 2+4 for filecontents header
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}
                [color=black,grid=major,use units, xlabel=x, ylabel=y,
                legend style={draw=none,fill=none,legend image post style={scale=1}, font=\scriptsize}, legend cell align={left}, legend pos=north west,]
                \addplot[dashed,draw=green, line width=1] table [x index=0,y index=1, ]{\curves};
                \addplot[       draw=green, line width=1] table [x index=0,y index=2, ]{\curves};
                \legend{curve1, curve2};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```